# Excel - Calculate the missing values using linear trend

Tags: excel, average, trend

Say i have a book where there is data in A1:B9.

A1:B9 has the values 1 though to 9. B1 contains the value 10 and B9 contains the value 60. See beloq

Is there a way to calculate what the values in between would be, assuming they fit on the line of best fit? The values would occupy abcdefg.

Cheers
Dale

```
  | A   B
____________
1 | 1   10
2 | 2   a
3 | 3   b
4 | 4   c
5 | 5   d
6 | 6   e
7 | 7   f
8 | 8   g
9 | 9   60
```

Answer (score 0):

In C2.

=FORECAST(A4,$B$1:$B$9,$A$1:$A$9)

Fill down.

Dont mind me.... 
Sorry

Comment: Dale's answer would work, if you re-arrange the rows (move row 9 to after row 1, and then use the formula as below) 
A       B
1 10
9 60
2 16.25 (=FORECASTA3,$B$1:$B$2,$A$1:$A$2)
3 22.5
4 28.75
5 35
6 41.25
7 47.5
8 53.75

Comment: I gave another answer. I think it works in some cases where the "simple" forecast does not. I tested a long time ago, and for some reason I stuck to the "complex" one.

Answer (score 0):

I use this

```
=FORECAST(NewX,OFFSET(KnownY,MATCH(NewX,KnownX,1)-1,0,2),OFFSET(KnownX,MATCH(NewX,KnownX,1)-1,0,2))
```

It works very well (from [here](http://www.blueleafsoftware.com/Products/Dagra/LinearInterpolationExcel.php)).